# How can I simulate an identity providers for SAML?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, simulator, idp

I'm writing some SSO code, that will allow any IdP that supports SAML to authorize with my code.
I need an IdP Simulator that can provide me a metadata URL with the Idp config so that I can test my code. (I'm providing in my code the SP config).

I search but couldn't find some kind of simulator, all I found were tools that manage the apps if I provide both the IdP and SP configs, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SAMLtest.id](https://samltest.id/) is a free SAML 2.0 testing service that allows you to test your SAML-compliant Service Provider (which is effectively what you have, based on your description). You need to upload a metadata document representing your SP / your application, and you'll be able to download the SAMLtest metadata to use to form your half of the integration.

This is effectively the *new* version of TestShib, which shut down a number of months ago due to lack of community support, and I use it relatively regularly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

(I) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository allows you to build and run a standalone IdP Simulator at your own testbed. Running a standalone SAML IdP Simulator by yourself allows you to test your SP code and debug your SAML SP log by checking server logs of both IdP and your SP developed by you.

(1) Download the source code from [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository

```
git clone https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP
```

(2) Copy your SP metadata file into

shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata/

(3) Extract IdP metadata file "idp-metadata.xml" from

shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata/

and upload it to your SP server developed by you

(4) Follow the README instruction to run OpenLDAP server and SAML IdP server using Docker container

(5) Run your SP server developed by you

(6) Now you can check the server logs of both Shibboleth IdP and your SP server to debug your SP code.

In addition, shibboleth-sp-testapp/ folder provides the reference SP configuration for your SP server developed by you.

(II) Another StackOverflow question [Setting up a new Shibboleth IdP to work with an existing SAML SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650374/setting-up-a-new-shibboleth-idp-to-work-with-an-existing-saml-sp/55540926#55540926) discusses the SAML configuration between IdP and SP.

(III) [TestShib](http://www.testshib.org/) is the online Shibboleth IdP simulator built and run by the Shibboleth community. It is exactly the same as the above standalone Shibboleth IdP simulator built and run by yourself.

Comment: finally something, that indeed works without 50 pages of instructions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also use SSOCircle , which offers a free of charge SAML IdP as well (https://www.ssocircle.com/en/portfolio/publicidp/). E.g. it is configured as a default SAML IdP for Spring Security SAML extension.