# Authentication/authorization provider: which one to choose for a 1 day project?

Tags: ldap, saml

For a **1 day project** (call it a hackathon) we will be looking into replacing a custom built authentication and authorization system with one that we can buy.
After all, there are people who are better at this stuff than we are.

- Non-cloud, hard requirement is *on-premise installation* possible
- Can authenticate against Active Directory using LDAP
- Can authenticate using SAML against ADFS
- Management of users, roles etc without a directory is an option (most likely option to actually use during the hackathon)
- Use open standards, SAML, OpenID, OAuth2

There are so many SAML-based products, but many are cloud-only, which unfortunately for us is not an option (reason: our products run on closed enterprise networks), so services like Okta are unfortunately not an option :(

The following list is quite complete, but doesn't give me any indication on how hard it is to install + **get up and running in a few hours**:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML-based_products_and_services

*Any suggestions for products to try?*

My eye caught these ones: 
miniOrange, Ping Identity, 10duke

[addition]
I am using a Java stack for web apps.

Answer (score 1):

[How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building a SAML-based Authentication/Authorization Provider using Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP.

- Shibboleth SAML IdP is responsible for identity federation.
- OpenLDAP is responsible for identity authentication.

I have validated SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) provided by Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP (Identity Provider) and OpenLDAP for the following enterprise applications. In other words, I leveraged Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP to log in to the following enterprise applications successfully.

```
Microsoft Office 365
Google G Suite
Salesforce
Dropbox
Box
Amazon AWS
OpenStack
Citrix NetScaler
VMware vCloud Director
Oracle NetSuite
```

Another StackOverflow question [Setting up a new Shibboleth IdP to work with an existing SAML SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650374/setting-up-a-new-shibboleth-idp-to-work-with-an-existing-saml-sp/55540926#55540926) discusses the SAML configuration between IdP and SP.

Answer (score 0):

OpenLDAP is not OpenID Connect or OAuth 2.0

Have a look at [identityserver4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/).

It's OpenID Connect / OAuth2 by design and it does have a plug-in SAML stack.

Or if you have a Windows server, use ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

FOSS - Shibboleth or KeyCloak

The definition of 'closed' (network) might be interesting to examine. No access to outside at all, not on any port, noway/nohow? In that case, yes, you want an on-prem service. If there's gated access to outside, it's likely that many hosted identity services could work.