# Trying to test SAML auth with open/free SAML IDP

Tags: saml, passport-saml

I am trying to test and debug SAML authentication with my app.  I currently do not have my own SAML IDP so I am trying to test with free/open SAML IDP providers.

Currently I am testing with SSOCircle: https://www.ssocircle.com/

And when testing after I sign in with that provider I get:

> Error occurred
>
> Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation.
>
> Please enable the additional debug option in "My Debug". Detailed
>   trace information only available with paid accounts. Check our plans.

Anyone successfully setup SAML auth within their app using SSOCircle. If so can you provide insight into what might be the problem.  I signed up for an account and registered my service provider on their site.

I have also looked around for simple free SAML testing IDPs without much luck.  If anyone has one they are using that is working that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Azure AD, Okta, Onelogin, Centrify.. all provide dev env for free SAML/OpenID Connect testing

Comment: Ok I will take look thanks!  I dug into OneLogin a bit but didn't see how without a trial account, I will keep looking

Comment: So does Auth0, samlidp.io, samltest, jumpcloud etc.

Comment: You may also look at https://www.ssocircle.com/en/portfolio/publicidp/

Comment: I provide Answer on how to configure standalone Shibboleth SAML IdP at StackOverflow question [Setting up a new Shibboleth IdP to work with an existing SAML SP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650374/setting-up-a-new-shibboleth-idp-to-work-with-an-existing-saml-sp/).and Answer on how to build and run standalone Shibboleth SAML IdP at StackOverflow question [connect to salesforce as SP from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604987/connect-to-salesforce-as-sp-from-java/).

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-idp-to-test-now-477761595b60

Answer (score 0):

using `http` in SSOCircle address instead of `https` has worked for me